# How to change default naming behavior of Fluent NHibernate for tables without an entity?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We have a database in a SQL Server that has been created using `Fluent Nhibernate` and `SchemaUpdate` and I want to copy its data to a Postgres database.

I used the same tools to make the database but **every table that doesn't has a matching entity (elements for example)** has its name in lowercase and also all column names are in lowercase.

The question is how can I tell `Fluent NHibernate` and/or `SchemaUpdate` to use `PascalCase` naming convention (as Sql Server)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions) to achieve this.

```
ConventionBuilder.Class.Always(x => x.Table(x.EntityType.Name.ToLower()))
```

above should allow to use lower case letters to the table name

```
ConventionBuilder.Class.When(
  c => c.Expect(x.TableName, Is.Not.Set), // when this is true
  x => x.Table(x.EntityType.Name + "Table") // do this
)
```

above is more complex, where if table name is not set, you can add a suffix.

Comment: Well I know that we can do that but the question is how . I mean which convention should I implement to tell the fluent nhibernate how to name columns of all tables or how to name tables that SchemaUpdate built on the fly.(using a hbm file of course)

Comment: Fluent hibernate does not use hbm files

Comment: Fluent NHibernate does not (though you can add hbm files to mappings) but SchemaUpdate use them to generate diff scripts.

Comment: The problem with your solution is `Elements` are not entities (no equivalent entity/class exists for them) so this convention will not affect their naming convention.In another word no `Elements` don't have any mapping.